# Thumbnails on wordpress will not resize

Tags: wordpress, resize, thumbnails

My thumbnails aren't resizing on my wordpress site. I have the following code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 66, 66, true );
```

I don't know what else to do.. When I upload an image, it remains original size. I have also set the thumbnail size to 66, 66 in media in admin. Still nothing. All my other images resize fine, just not the thumbnail/feature images.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

can you upload a new image and also use [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)  plugin to re-size the old images
Thanks

Comment: Can you send me the link where the image is placed?